# KSP with Version Catalog

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin-symbol-processing

i want to migrate from kapt to ksp and all is done.
but if i combine version catalog with ksp, error is show.

this is my code on gradle previously and all is done.
`ksp "androidx.room:room-compiler:$version"`

BUT
if i combine with version catalog, the error is show,

gradle:
`kasp(libs.room.compiler)`

error:

> Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method kasp() for arguments [map(valueof(DependencyValueSource))] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler

actually, i can make the code as this, but i don't want to use it
`ksp "androidx.room:room-compiler:${libs.versions.room.get()}"`

i just want to keep like this `kasp(libs.room.compiler)`

sorry if my explanation is wrong and ambigous

expect: `kasp(libs.room.compiler) with no error`

reality:

> Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method kasp() for arguments [map(valueof(DependencyValueSource))] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler

try: `ksp "androidx.room:room-compiler:${libs.versions.room.get()}"`

Answer (score 0):

You've said `kasp` but it looks like a typo.

```
ksp(libs.room.compiler)
```

Works for me